# Passing MongoDB data into .ejs with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

Route:

```
        app.get('/admin/cardapio', function(req, res) {
            Produtos.find({}).exec(function(err, produtos) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.render('admin/cardapio.ejs', { data: produtos});
            });
        });
```

Table:

```
                <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {%>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= data[i]._id %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].description %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].type %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].price %></td>
                    <td>EDITAR / REMOVER</td>
                  </tr>
                  <%}%>
```

Mongo DB result:

```
{
    "title" : "teste",
    "description" : "teste",
    "price" : "20",
    "type" : "teste",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2790f7f9f2ab37e813504d"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

When I use only `data[i]` on each row, it shows the whole result, but If I put the `.title` it doesn't show anything, and when I put `_id` from mongodb it shows normally

[with `data[i]._id` on first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79iZr.png)

Comment: Are you saying that _id is the only field you can get to show up on your EJS page?  Can you console.log(data[i].title)?

Comment: yes, if I do a <% console.log(data[i].title) %> it doesn't show anything on console

Comment: Sorry, I asked that in a confusing way. What I meant to ask was: In your route, can you loop through produtos and console.log that either?

Comment: yes, http://prntscr.com/jyhbr0

Comment: Okay, last one: try adding "produtos = Array.from(produtos);" on the line after "if (err) throw err"

Comment: nope, same thing

Comment: Can you please post more code? Something else must be causing this.

Comment: yep, saw it now, forgot to change the fields on the model, thanks, I spent almost 4 days trying to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Route .js

```
app.get('/admin/cardapio', function(req, res) {
    Produtos.find({}, function(err, produtos) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render('admin/cardapio.ejs', { data: produtos});
            }
        });
});
```

EJS file

```
  <% data.forEach(function(foundData, i){%>
    <tr>
    <td><%= foundData.title %></td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
```

**Can you test?**

Answer (score 0):

use **forEach** loop as below :

```
<% data.forEach(function(product){  %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= product.title %></td>
                    <td><%= product._id %></td>
                    <td><%= product.description %></td>
                    <td><%= product.type %></td>
                    <td><%= product.price %></td>
                    <td>EDITAR / REMOVER</td>
                  </tr>
<%})%>
```

or if you want to use **for loop** :

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {%>
                  <tr>
                     <td><%= data[i]["title"] %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i]["_id"] %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i]["description"] %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i]["type"] %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i]["price"] %></td>
                    <td>EDITAR / REMOVER</td>
                  </tr>
                  <%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The presence of `"__v" : 0` in your MongoDB and the `.exec()` methods that you're using implies that you're using Mongoose as an ODM (can you confirm this to me ?).

The result that your query returns is not a JSON Object but a Mongoose model instance. That's why you need to call `.toJSON()` on your result :

`res.render('admin/cardapio.ejs', { data: produtos.map(p => p.toJSON()) });`

Answer (score 0):

Try to lean Your result, it converts mongoose objects to generic json objects

```
app.get('/admin/cardapio', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Produtos.find({}).lean();    
    res.render('admin/cardapio', {products});
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Oops..');
  }
});
```

EJS file

```
<% products.forEach(function(product, index) { %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.title %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= product.type %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td>
      <a href="/path/to/edit/<%= product._id %>">EDITAR</a>
      / 
      <a href="/path/to/delete/<%= product._id %>">REMOVER</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% }) %>
```