# Fetching data from MongoDB & displaying only one parameter in HTML

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

I am having some difficulty in retrieving just 'username' from MongoDB database & then displaying that in a message "Hello, username" using EJS template.

MongoDB data in the following format. There are multiple data entries, and for whoever is logged in, his username should be displayed. Eg: here username is "Aarav".

```
_id: 6026cfsfsd3545d8515a8db8010
username: "Aarav"
email: "test@gmail.com"
password: "$2a$12$HOPcz4tkcpiGV6X39HntLudfsdfsfsdhdvgdhde"
```

In EJS, I want to put dynamic data of username instead of current manual input -

```
<header class="header">
      <nav class="main-header__nav">
        <% if (isAuthenticated) { %>
        <a href="/dashboard">
          <img src="/img/logo.jpg" alt="zxzxz" class="logo" />
        </a>
        <h1 class="title-nav">Hello, Aarav!</h1>
          <% } %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997071/passing-mongodb-data-into-ejs-with-node-js

Comment: Thanks, everywhere entire database looping is done. I only want to do this for the user that's logged in.